# How to resolve javascript: SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined in Edge (works fine in Chrome and IE)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, people-picker

I just noticed a javascript function that finds and populates people picker controls in SharePoint was not working in Edge, whereas it works fine in Chrome and IE.

In Edge I see an error in the console log related to the code below: 'SPClientPeoplePicker' is not defined

```
    var controlName = "External";
    var ppDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
    var ppEditor = ppDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
    var spPP = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv[0].id];

    ppEditor.val(cuser);
    spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
```

Has anyone else come across this? If so, any solutions?

Comment: Is there any updates ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to clientpeoplepicker.js will fix this error in Edge Browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.setTimeout(function() {
      SetAndResolvePeoplePicker("Account Manager", _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName);
      }, 750);



function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName,Name) 
{

        var controlName = fieldName;
        var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
        var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
        var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
        peoplePickerEditor.val(Name);
        spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SetAndResolvePeoplePicker(fieldName, userAccountName) {

var controlName = fieldName;

var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");

var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");

var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];

peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);

spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);

//disable the field

spPeoplePicker.SetEnabledState(false);

//hide the delete/remove use image from the people picker

$('.sp-peoplepicker-delImage').css('display','none');

}
```

https://peakfinders.blogspot.com/2015/10/spclientpeoplepicker-is-undefined.html